# How to get BSON UTC datetime value in Node / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to save an entry in a MongoDB time series collection, but I'm unable to store the timeField correctly, mongo is throwing the error.
`MongoServerError: 'blockTime' must be present and contain a valid BSON UTC datetime value`
How can I convert a Date object to a BSON UTC date time?

Below is the schema

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const tradeSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    blockTime: {
      type: Number,
    },
  },
  {
    timeseries: {
      timeField: "blockTime",
    },
  }
);

const Trade = mongoose.model("trade", tradeSchema);

export default Trade;
```

Below is the code that is generating the error

```
const newTrade = new Trade({
  blockTime: new Date().valueOf(),
});

await newTrade.save();
```

Comment: Try using the value returned by the `valueOf` method of date objects.  `new Date().valueOf()` returns the number of milliseconds since the start of the Unix epoch. I would expect the (JS) drivers for MongoDB to accept JavaScript numbers as input.

Comment: Still I'm getting the errror `MongoServerError: 'blockTime' must be present and contain a valid BSON UTC datetime value`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the type of the blockTime should be Date instead of Number, when I changed the type to Date, it worked

Comment: This makes sense of a line I didn't understand in (the accepted) answer to ["Conversion from string to boson.date](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/conversion-from-string-to-bson-date/124243) in a MongoDb forum: "... conversion  [to bson date type] happens only if you supply the driver with appropriate convertible data type - and for NodeJS / JavaScript applications it is the Date object." Thanks, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
blockTime: new Date()
```

Mondodb will intelligently handle the rest.